# What files can be safely deleted from the MinGW-w64 binaries?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

I am using the `MinGW-w64` installer found here:
https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds

Installing to a directory creates a folder called `mingw32` or `mingw64` that contains the compiler. I already know that the additional batch script, HTML link, and uninstall executable in the same directory can be deleted.

The `mingw32/64` folder contains these folders:

> 1. bin
> 2. etc
> 3. include
> 4. lib
> 5. libexec
> 6. licenses
> 7. opt
> 8. share
> 9. i686-w64-mingw32 (mingw32) or x86_64-w64-mingw32 (mingw64)

I only wish to compile with `C` and nothing else. So what files can I delete in order to reduce the file count because the compiler contains files for `Ruby`, `Fortran` and other languages which as I stated, I don't need it.

Comment: Delete something, see if your code still compiles. Repeat until no further deletions possible

Comment: Have you found a solution to what files you can delete?

Answer (score 1):

Why are people still using Mingw or Mingw64 instead of [TDM-GCC](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/) ? You have to rely on the default builds or build it yourself from source. Trying to install it on your own terms sucks.

[TDM-GCC](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/) on the other hand, you can specify where and which components to install as you wish. You can upgrade or remove it without any worries. It's more fast, easy,modern and equivelant these days.

Now for your question, you can download and install [TDM-GCC](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/) by it's [installer](https://github.com/jmeubank/tdm-gcc/releases/download/v9.2.0-tdm-1/tdm-gcc-9.2.0.exe). I don't really think you need any further instructions as a 5 year old would understand how to use it. Just select only the components required for c.

If you don't understand,I would gladly help you more if needed. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you want a smaller GCC toolset, try [MinGW Distro](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html).

Scroll down to "How To Build Your Own Distro", download components-14.1.7z, extract it, extract binutils 2.27 and GCC 6.3.0 inside the same folder. The total size is about 270MB.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know the minimum are yours

1, bin
5. libexec

not all tools in bin you may need but generally i would hold both of those dirs

you also ned libraries and headers if you want to build abainst standard c library and windows.h, so

3. include
4. lib

is also needed (hovever part of it may contain also headers and libraries for c++ standard library) all those main 3 libs are kinda mixed there afaik so it might be a bit hard to find what comes for what